# Function I have defined will not plot

Tags: plotting

My Mathematica plot is coming out as blank. I am trying to plot my eigenfunction `Ψ1`.

Here is my code. What am I doing wrong?

```
Ψ1[x_] := sqrt[2/L] sin[{Pi x}/{L}];
L = 1;
Plot[Ψ1[x], {x, 0, L}]
```

[image]

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Answer (score 6):

Use `Sqrt[]` not `sqrt[]` and `Sin[]` not `sin[]`. For coupling/grouping use `()` not `{}`.

```
F[x_] := Sqrt[2/L] Sin[(Pi x)/L];
L = 1;
Plot[F[x], {x, 0, L}]
```

Comment: When You get a blank plot, it means that evaluation of your expression does not yield a real number. In that case, simply trying out your expression on a number will usually help show you what the problem is.